# What algorithm browsers follow to remember values for form controls?

Tags: browser

You can have different HTML `input` elements on a single HTML `form` and all of them, have their associated remembered values (values that you've entered in those fields); Is it related to the `id` or `name` attribute of the `input` element? No. Proof? Your email address appears on many `input` elements across different websites, and all those fields have different `id` and `name` attributes.

So, there is a mystery here I don't understand. How browsers remember values for HTML form controls? What is the algorithm? How they know that they should show your email on *this* control and not on *that* control, while controls are both HTML `input type=text` elements?

Comment: It is related to the name attribute.

Comment: Close voter, would you mind please telling us why? Is it an off-topic question? Is it not constructive? What is the reason to vote for closing?

Answer (score 3):

Browser are checking for similarity between input elements' name attributes. Also, there are standard names for input fields defined in [RFC 3106](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3106.txt). Also look [here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Toolbar/thread?tid=7ce6293ebaa69edb&hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers use different algorithms. I know if I were building one I would wind up

- checking if the fields name/id has 'email' in it
- checking if the label text has 'email' in it
- checking for common abbreviations
- (if I were google) keeping track of all the forms everyone inputs and seeing which ones get email address looking strings put in them. Since I'm google I can totally do that ;).